# About Integrability of a function

Tags: calculus, analysis

I was assigned the following problem:
Lef $f$ be an integrable function in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x)<1,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and such that $f(1)=1.$ Show that the function $g$ defined by
$$g(x)=\begin{cases} e^{f(x)}-e^x & if\ \ x\neq1\\ e & if\ x=1 \end{cases}$$
is integrable in every subset f the real line.
Question is, will i have to show that $f$ is monotonic in order to show integrability?

Comment: $g$ is discontinuous only at $x=1$. There is no need to show monotonicity.

Comment: The rest of the hypotheses are superfluous?

Comment: As stated, yeah. Are you sure you mean $f'(x)<1$ for any real $x$? Because that implies $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Ah, forget it. I was just considering bounded subsets of the real numbers. My bad.

Comment: So, why do they provide a bound for $f'$?

Comment: An estimate for the derivative can be used with the Mean Value Theorem. That and $f(1)=1$ gives $f(x)<x$.